# MySql Join tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables like this.

Table 1 Fields:
CId , Name
Table 2 Fields:
CId , food

I want to get no. of food against each CId with the query "select * from table1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that should work:

```
SELECT
  t1.* , count(t2.food) as foods
FROM
  t1 LEFT JOIN t2 on (t1.Cid = t2.Cid)
GROUP BY
  t2.Cid
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   food
FROM
   Table2 t2
   JOIN Table1 t1 ON (t2.Cld = t1.Cld)
```

Comment: I just want to get no. of foods against each CId not the food itselft

Comment: replace ' food' with Count(food)

Comment: The JOIN would require the existence of food in t2, so the records from t1 which do not have any food in t2 will be ignored from the resultset.

Comment: Also if i understand this correctly, the lack of group by would cause to count all rows and not just the ones linked the t1 record.

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.name, b.food from table1 a, table1 b where a.cld = b.cld;
```